# Finding $f(n)=f(f(n-1))+f(f(n+1))$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, functional-equations

Determine whether a function exists from the positive integers to the positive integers which satisfies the equation: 
$$f(n)=f(f(n-1))+f(f(n+1))$$.

My guess is that this function does not exist, as through trial and error I found that $f(n)=\frac{n}{2}$ is a solution to the functional equation. Obviously this is not enough, but I don't know how to tackle this problem.

I found that $f(n+2)-f(n)=f(f(n+3))-f(f(n-1))$, but this doesn't seem very useful to me.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sketch of the proof that no such function exists. Say that such a function does exist. Take $n$ be such that $f(n)=m$ is the minimum value that $f$ takes. If $n\neq1$, then then $m$ is expressed as the sum of two outputs of the function $f$ by the given relation. Since the outputs of $f$ are positive integers, this is impossible.

If the minimum is $f(1)$ and is attained only at $1$, then take let $n_1>1$ be such that $f(n_1)$ is the minimum of the values attained by $f$ excluding $f(1)$. Then $f(n_1+1)\geq f(n_1)>f(1)\geq 1$, so by the minimality of $f(n_1)$, we have that $f(f(n_1+1))\geq f(n_1)$. Again this leaves the desired relation impossible, so there is no such function.

Comment: You should rule out the case $n=1$, for which the formula does not apply, as $f(n-1)$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and good answer! But on that note, what would I have to do to turn this answer from a sketch to a full proof?  It seems fairly complete to me.

Comment: For starters, address the good point that @AndreasT raises about the case that the minimum is $f(1)$ and is attained only there. I will edit to address this case.